# at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When i am runing this code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Next']")).click();
```

I am getting this error

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
at com.edureka.waits.LoginToGmail.main(LoginToGmail.java:21)
```

Here is the tag I am working on

```
<span jsname="V67aGc" class="VfPpkd-vQzf8d">Next</span>
```

Any ideas on how I should go about troubleshooting? Thanks!